# react native: Play Store have problem with permisson (CAMERA, RECORD_AUDIO, ...) after upload the apk

Tags: android, react-native, expo

i tried upload my build with my application to internal tester on playStore. The playStore giving me an error saying:

> Your APK or Android App Bundle is using permissions that require a
>   privacy policy: （Camera, record audio, phone state， read contacts).

In my app.json of my react native project, I have not provided this so I tried manually added on

> "android" : ["CAMERA", "RECORD_AUDIO", "READ_PHONE_STATE",
>   "READ_CONTACTS"]

The result is the same

Comment: `require a privacy policy` means that you have to specify privacy policy url in the play store

Comment: okay so is not the permission itself.. where should I set this url

Comment: If your app is using CALENDAR,CAMERA,CONTACTS,LOCATION,MICROPHONE,PHONE,SENSORS,SMS,STORAGE).Then you need to provide a privacy policies in your play store console. To add privacy policies follow these steps.

Go to your Google Play Console Select an app Select “Store presence > Store listing” Under “Privacy Policy add the privacy policies URL.

That's it!!! You can now submit your app.

Comment: in the google play store on the page where you publish the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is using CALENDAR,CAMERA,CONTACTS,LOCATION,MICROPHONE,PHONE,SENSORS,SMS,STORAGE).Then you need to provide a privacy policies in your play store console. 
To add privacy policies follow these steps.

Go to your Google Play Console
Select an app
Select “Store presence > Store listing”
Under “Privacy Policy add the privacy policies URL.

That's it!!! You can now submit your app.

Comment: You can create privacy policy from this URL --  > https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: Good one. Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload Privacy policy URL in the Store listing section in your Play Console if you're using any "Dangerous Permissions" like CAMERA, READ_SMS, RECORD_AUDIO, etc.

Go to:

> Click on the app in Play Console -> Store Presence -> Store listing -> See the bottom most element

You can use the following website to generate Privacy Policy quickly.

[Privacy policy generator](https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/)